# table-layout: fixed percentage and calc not working

Tags: html, css, fixed-header-tables

I have a table with many rows, for which I want to overlay a fixed table header when scrolling. The layout of the page is responsive with a fixed with left hand menu that can have 1 of 2 fixed widths. I am having problems aligning the columns in the fixed header with the table.

As per this fiddle

```css
body {
  width: 1519px;
}

#fixedheader {
  width: calc (100% - 100px);
}

#contenttable {
  width: 100%;
}

#fixedheader {
  width: calc(100% - 100px);
  position: fixed;
  top: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.donor_name_header {
  width: calc((100% - 100px)/5);
}

.total_row_header,
.total_variance_header {
  width: calc((100% - 100px)/10);
}

.bar0 {
  background-color: #CCFFCC;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="100px">Left column, width may change between 2 values</td>
        <td style="position: relative;">

          <table id="fixedheader">
            <thead>

              <tr>
                <th style="width:20%;">
                  &nbsp;
                  <!--placehold header row in data block-->
                </th>
                <th style="width: 5.8333333333333%">
                  Jan 17 </th>
                <th style="width: 5.8333333333333%">
                  Feb 17 </th>
                <th style="width: 5.8333333333333%">
                  Mar 17 </th>
                <th style="width: 5.8333333333333%">
                  Apr 17 </th>
                <th style="width: 5.8333333333333%">
                  May 17 </th>
                <th style="width: 5.8333333333333%">
                  Jun 17 </th>
                <th style="width: 5.8333333333333%">
                  Jul 17 </th>
                <th style="width: 5.8333333333333%">
                  Aug 17 </th>
                <th style="width: 5.8333333333333%">
                  Sep 17 </th>
                <th style="width: 5.8333333333333%">
                  Oct 17 </th>
                <th style="width: 5.8333333333333%">
                  Nov 17 </th>
                <th style="width: 5.8333333333333%">
                  Dec 17 </th>
                <th style="width:10%;">
                  Total&nbsp;
                  <!--placehold header row in data block-->
                </th>
                <th style="width:10%;">
                  <!--placehold header row in data block-->
                </th>
              </tr>

            </thead>
          </table>
          <table id="contenttable">
            <thead>

              <tr>
                <th style="width:20%;">
                  &nbsp;
                  <!--placehold header row in data block-->
                </th>
                <th style="width: 5.8333333333333%">
                  Jan 17 </th>
                <th style="width: 5.8333333333333%">
                  Feb 17 </th>
                <th style="width: 5.8333333333333%">
                  Mar 17 </th>
                <th style="width: 5.8333333333333%">
                  Apr 17 </th>
                <th style="width: 5.8333333333333%">
                  May 17 </th>
                <th style="width: 5.8333333333333%">
                  Jun 17 </th>
                <th style="width: 5.8333333333333%">
                  Jul 17 </th>
                <th style="width: 5.8333333333333%">
                  Aug 17 </th>
                <th style="width: 5.8333333333333%">
                  Sep 17 </th>
                <th style="width: 5.8333333333333%">
                  Oct 17 </th>
                <th style="width: 5.8333333333333%">
                  Nov 17 </th>
                <th style="width: 5.8333333333333%">
                  Dec 17 </th>
                <th style="width:10%;">
                  Total&amp;n
                  <table id="fixedheader" style="display: none;">
                    <thead>

                      <tr>
                        <th style="width:20%;">
                          &nbsp;
                          <!--placehold header row in data block-->
                        </th>
                        <th style="width: 5.8333333333333%">
                          Jan 17 </th>
                        <th style="width: 5.8333333333333%">
                          Feb 17 </th>
                        <th style="width: 5.8333333333333%">
                          Mar 17 </th>
                        <th style="width: 5.8333333333333%">
                          Apr 17 </th>
                        <th style="width: 5.8333333333333%">
                          May 17 </th>
                        <th style="width: 5.8333333333333%">
                          Jun 17 </th>
                        <th style="width: 5.8333333333333%">
                          Jul 17 </th>
                        <th style="width: 5.8333333333333%">
                          Aug 17 </th>
                        <th style="width: 5.8333333333333%">
                          Sep 17 </th>
                        <th style="width: 5.8333333333333%">
                          Oct 17 </th>
                        <th style="width: 5.8333333333333%">
                          Nov 17 </th>
                        <th style="width: 5.8333333333333%">
                          Dec 17 </th>
                        <th style="width:10%;">
                          Total&nbsp;
                          <!--placehold header row in data block-->
                        </th>
                        <th style="width:10%;">
                          <!--placehold header row in data block-->
                        </th>
                      </tr>

                    </thead>
                  </table>bsp;
                  <!--placehold header row in data block-->
                </th>
                <th style="width:10%;">
                  <!--placehold header row in data block-->
                </th>
              </tr>

            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr class="each_donor">
                <td class="donor_name none" rowspan="2" style="width: 20%;">
                  <p> First Last</p>
                  <p>First & Other Last</p>
                </td>

                <td class="detail_month" style="width: 5.8333333333333%">
                  <span class="variance"><sup>&nbsp;</sup></span>
                </td>
                <td class="detail_month" style="width: 5.8333333333333%">
                  <span class="variance"><sup>&nbsp;</sup></span>
                </td>
                <td class="detail_month" style="width: 5.8333333333333%">
                  <span class="variance"><sup>&nbsp;</sup></span>
                </td>
                <td class="detail_month" style="width: 5.8333333333333%">
                  <span class="variance"><sup>&nbsp;</sup></span>
                </td>
                <td class="detail_month" style="width: 5.8333333333333%">
                  <span class="variance"><sup>&nbsp;</sup></span>
                </td>
                <td class="detail_month" style="width: 5.8333333333333%">
                  <span class="variance"><sup>&nbsp;</sup></span>
                </td>
                <td class="detail_month" style="width: 5.8333333333333%">
                  <span class="variance"><sup>&nbsp;</sup></span>
                </td>
                <td class="detail_month" style="width: 5.8333333333333%">
                  <span class="variance"><sup>&nbsp;</sup></span>
                </td>
                <td class="detail_month" style="width: 5.8333333333333%">
                  <span class="variance"><sup>&nbsp;</sup></span>
                </td>
                <td class="detail_month" style="width: 5.8333333333333%">
                  <span class="variance"><sup>&nbsp;</sup></span>
                </td>
                <td class="detail_month" style="width: 5.8333333333333%">
                  <span class="variance"><sup>&nbsp;</sup></span>
                </td>
                <td class="detail_month" style="width: 5.8333333333333%">
                  <span class="variance"><sup>&nbsp;</sup></span>
                </td>
                <td class="total_row" rowspan="2">
                  $360.00 </td>
                <td class="total_variance" rowspan="2">
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="recurring_period colspan bar0" colspan="12">
                  $30.00 monthly </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <script>
    // tell the embed parent frame the height of the content
    if (window.parent && window.parent.parent) {
      window.parent.parent.postMessage(["resultsFrame", {
        height: document.body.getBoundingClientRect().height,
        slug: "None"
      }], "*")
    }
  </script>





</body>
```

I cannot find a way to calculate the percentage of the first and last 2 columns correctly. I have tried:

- width: calc(20% - 20px);
- width: 20%;
- width: calc(100%-100px)/5; (which seems correct to me and is in snippet)

Unfortunately I can also not move the position: relative to the top

Comment: This question has far too many fundamental errors in the markup to make it worthwhile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have fixed table layout check "[CSS Only Fixed Table Headers](https://codepen.io/tjvantoll/pen/JEKIu)" on codepen

But if you have dynamic content or a lot of data in a table, you can use `position: relative`  and change `top` property  with js.

Here is a [simple codepen](https://codepen.io/Xopoc/pen/mXbyEZ) to better understand how to do it.
Of course, there are some pros and cons of this method.

### Pros

- all widths are calculated in browser-side, so your table header and columns are always the same width
- you use the same table row, so don't need to duplicate any data
- the only calculations on js side is scroll position and position of the header, no need to calculate column widths
- more table data don't slow down calculations, so basically table can be really big.

### Cons:

- Js based solution
- scroll events can be really slow.
- more tables slow down calculations
- styling is very limited

Also, there are a lot of other js plugins to make table header fixed

Answer (score 2):

It appears that there is a combination of several issues:

Firstly, `.fixedheader, .contenttable, .donor_name_header, .total_row_header, .total_variance_header` all of these classes are not used in the HTML. This can be fixed by using `class="fixedHeader"` in the HTML.

Secondly, it appears that you have used `style="width: 10px"` attribute in your HTML, this must be removed on elements with classes as it will override any changes in you CSS.

Additionally, the % unit is relative to an element's parent object, I believe you are trying to calculate it based off of the window width and in that case it would make more sense to use `100vw` (viewport width), which is relative to the width of the window.

Furthermore, the code never sets the css property `table-layout: fixed` on the table

Comment: This may not fix all the problems, but it will certainly be a stepping stone to the right direction. Once you have tried implementing this, we can continue to work it out.

Comment: sorry haved fixed .fixedheader to #fixedheader, but need more fixes. I had to strip down a quite complex page to this snippet, may also move this to jsfiddle. Good point about style="width", will get back to you

Comment: Add to the list, there is no required space before and after the subtraction mark. calc(100% - 100px)/5 and the division takes place outside the parenthesis.

Comment: @jdog You are required to post your problem markup here within your question. Do not move it to a jsfiddle. [mcve]